# QtCreator continuously saves .pro.user file inside a project

Tags: qt-creator, synchronization, dropbox, continuous, autosave

I'm experiencing an annoying behavior of `QtCreator`: when a project is open, `QtCreator` keeps saving the project's `.pro.user` file over and over, about every 10 seconds. Given that my projects are under the `Dropbox` folder, I see the `Dropbox` icon spinning forever. I don't remember having seen this behavior before, anybody has hints about this?

This is my version of `QtCreator`:

```
Qt Creator 2.5.2
Based on Qt 4.8.2 (64 bit)
Built on Sep 22 2012 at 14:57:50
```

It's not a `Dropbox` sync issue, because if I stop my other PC's instance, the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's default behavior in 2.5, but seems like it wont be for too long...

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/19491

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for the link. I'll wait for an update then.